# How do I apply a patch with Composer workflow?

Tags: 8, composer, version-control

I need to include a patch in my project. I have included cweagans/composer-patches in composer.json and added the following lines in the extra section (example is from when trying to enable distribution in the Configuration installer).

```
"patches": {
        "drupal/config_installer": {
            "Enable distribution for Configuration installer profile": "patches/config_installer_enable_distribution.patch"
        }
    }
```

Afterwards, I run `composer update`.

```
- Installing drupal/config_installer (1.5.0): Loading from cache
- Applying patches for drupal/config_installer
    patches/config_installer_enable_distribution.patch (Enable distribution for Configuration installer profile)
```

So I get no errors and the patch seems to have been applied successfully. Also the file `PATCHES.txt` is successfully created in the package's root directory. Still, **the patch hasn't been applied**.

I've tried this method with other packages which come from Github and it works, however every time I try this with a module or a profile from drupal.org then the patch isn't being applied.

Am I missing anything?

When I ran `composer update -vvv`, I saw the command which is running for the patch is indeed with Git.

```
git -C 'web/profiles/contrib/config_installer' apply '-p1' '/path/to/project/patches/config_installer_enable_distribu‌​‌​tion.patch'
```

I've tried running the command by itself; again, it didn't change the file.

Comment: Are you positive the patch hasn't been applied? Have you applied it manually to the same file/directory and confirmed there's a different result? It would be weird for the patch attempt to raise no errors/feedback but still fail

Comment: What operating system are you on? If you are on OSX you will need to install gpatch. Are you sure the patch path is correct?

Comment: Also you say the patch is from drupal.org but the path doesn’t indicate that. You can enter an https url to the patch on drupal.org and it will fetch it.

Comment: I opened the respective file and the changes are not there. Also I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with PHP7. I didn't say the patch was from drupal.org but the package is. When e.g. I tried the above with [Commerce Base](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce_base) the patch worked. I also tried with a patch from drupal.org but the result was the same.

Comment: @Kevin You don't need gpatch (I'm on OSX and don't have it installed, my composer patches work great)

Comment: @Thomas But have you **manually** applied the patch and confirmed that the results are different? That's the only test you can do to know which one of either the Composer patching process or the patch file itself is at fault

Comment: Run composer with `composer update -vvv` to check which shell commands were executed during the run (e.g. `git`) and paste the relevant part.

Comment: Yes, when running the patch from within the project directory using `patch -p1 < /path/to/patch/file.patch` then it works as expected. When running `composer update -vvv` I saw the command which is running for the patch is indeed with git: `git -C 'web/profiles/contrib/config_installer' apply '-p1' '/path/to/project/patches/config_installer_enable_distribu‌​tion.patch'`. I tried running the command by itself and again it didn't change the file.

Comment: He's on Ubuntu but it was just a thought. @Clive see: https://github.com/acquia/blt/issues/2251#issuecomment-342665375  using a certain version of git and OSX can cause patches to not apply in some cases.

Comment: Wow, that's some edge case @Kevin. Cheers for the link

Comment: Yep, I ran right into it. Was tough to narrow down. Composer Patches was recently updated, as was Composer.

Answer (score 15):

**First**, run

```bash
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

Now you have a package installed that enables you to patch core, libraries or modules.

**Second**, add a patch to a folder named 'patches' in the root (where your composer.json file is).

**Third**, add an "extras" section in composer with a patch:

```json
"extra": {
    "patches": {
        "drupal/core": {
            "Undocumented title variable in feed-icon.html.twig": "patches/3156260-11.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```json
"extra": {
    "patches-file": "composer.patches.json"
}
```

with a composer.patches.json file that contains patches like this:

```json
{
    "patches": {
        "drupal/core": {
            "Undocumented title variable in feed-icon.html.twig": "patches/3156260-11.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

**Fourth**, run

```bash
composer install
```

This will remove the core, re-download and patch it. Same goes for modules and libraries.

**Side note**: you can also use an external url of the patch instead of a local file in your patches folder.

**Source**: section 1.1.3 of https://stefvanlooveren.me/courses/drupal-9-framework#toc

Comment: This is the best way to do it as it works with modules that are installed normally with composer. Make sure you have the cweagans composer-patches and the patches config in extra will work. You can use the patch url from drupal.org as well, but those can be removed.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is that composer is applying patches using `git apply` which is not working for packages that are not installed from source.

Therefore the solution is to install the packages from source. This way the package will fetch the package along with its repository (when available) thus enabling it to be patched.

So...

### How to install/update a package from source

#### For new packages:

Use

```
composer require vendor/package --prefer-source
```

#### For existing packages

If your package is already installed then you need to delete it so that you can re-fetch it with `composer install` ([there is no `composer reinstall` command](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3112)). Do so and then use

```
composer install vendor/package --prefer-source
```

#### Set it as the default behavior

You can also set it up as the default behavior for the project in the `config` section of `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
      "preferred-install": "source"
    },
```

Update:

#### Set it as the default behavior for a specific package

In case you don't want to set your entire project to install from source, you can do so for a specific package only. To do so you need to specify the [VCS Branch](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#branches) in the Version constrain of the package.

```
"require": {
        "vendor/package": "dev-branch#branch-hash"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To apply a patch in drupal 8, edit the composer.json file and find the extra section -

```
"extra": {
    .
    .
    .
    "patches": {
        "drupal/MODULE_NAME": {
            "ANY_STRING_TO_NAME_THE_APPLYING_PATCH": "PATCH URL"
        }
    },
    "enable-patching": true
}
```

For Example -

```
"extra": {
    "installer-types": [
        "bower-asset",
        "npm-asset"
    ],
    "patches": {
        "drupal/recaptcha": {
            "Drupal recaptcha ajax fix syncing": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-04-17/recaptcha-ajax-2493183-172.patch"
        }
    },
    "enable-patching": true
}
```

Then, run composer install and your patch is applied.

If you want to apply multiple patches for same package, add new key inside the package name

Example :-

```
"patches": {
   "drupal/MODULE_NAME": {
          "Patch name 1": "Patch 1 Url", 
          "Patch name 2": "Patch 2 Url" 
        }
    },
```

Comment: Why is the "enable-patching": true. Is this necessary?

Comment: @StefVanLooveren You should use it if you want your project to accept patches from dependencies: https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches#allowing-patches-to-be-applied-from-dependencies