# How do I apply path alias patch?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I am updating a site from Drupal 8.7 to Drupal 8.8, and after running a drush updb, I encountered this error:

```
[error]  TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\pathauto\AliasStorageHelper::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\path_alias\AliasRepositoryInterface, instance of Drupal\Core\Path\AliasRepository given, called in drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 289 in Drupal\pathauto\AliasStorageHelper->__construct() (line 79 of drupal/modules/contrib/pathauto/src/AliasStorageHelper.php) #0 drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(289): Drupal\pathauto\AliasStorageHelper->__construct(Object(Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory), Object(Drupal\Core\Path\AliasRepository), Object(Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection), Object(Drupal\pathauto\VerboseMessenger), Object(Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationManager), Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager))
```

I found a similar issue in [this link here](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto/issues/3131286) and there seems to be a solution(patch) for it.

EDIT:

I ran a composer command attempting to fix the path alias error:

composer require 'drupal/pathauto:1.x-dev@dev'

Ran composer update, and drush updb.
The following is the error displayed by the console:

```
>  [error]  Argument 2 passed to Drupal\pathauto\AliasStorageHelper::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\path_alias\AliasRepositoryInterface, instance of Drupal\Core\Path\AliasRepository given
>  [error]  Update failed: block_field_update_8001
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Drupal\path_alias\AliasRepository does not exist in /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php:1174
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(1174): ReflectionClass->__construct('Drupal\\path_ali...')
> #1 /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(634): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition), Array, true, 'path_alias.repo...')
> #2 /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(1281): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet('path_alias.repo...', 1, Array, true)
> #3 /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(1238): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doResolveServices(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference), Array, true)
> #4 /var/www/html/docroot/ in /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 1174
 [error]  Update aborted by: system_update_8803, block_field_update_8001
 [error]  Finished performing updates.
```

Is there anything else I can do with the pathauto module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I apply a patch with Composer workflow?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251345/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-with-composer-workflow)

Comment: No it does not @leymannx

Comment: Try manually downloading the latest version and unzip into /modules folder, so it overrides and then run `drush updb`. The patch is alrdy in the latest version; thus, no need to apply it.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/3089457

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean of "apply a patch" on a drupal module?
You should use [composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches), the github page cleary explain of setup it and use for a patch modules\core.

In your case it should be somethings like:

```
{
  "require": {
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.0",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "source"
  },
  "extra": {
    "patches": {
      "drupal/pathauto": {
        "issue name": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-04-27/3131286-3.patch"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this issue is already "fixed", so it is already in the dev version of the module. Applying on the stable one could fail, so you'd just have to switch to the dev version of the module, aka

```
composer require 'drupal/pathauto:1.x-dev@dev'
```

Please note that is best to avoid on production dev version unless strictly necessary. In other words, if you switch to dev, you should update to the next release of pathauto asap it's released

Comment: for some reason am still getting the same error. I added the composer require line, ran composer update, and drush updb. For the drush, the console still threw the same error message. I edited the question based on your answer.

Comment: What do you mean with " I added the composer require line"? Maybe I wasn't clear on this part: that command shouldn't be added directly to the composer.json file, it is a command that you should run from the terminal, at the same level where the composer.json it is. If done correctly, you should find in the composer.json " "drupal/pathauto": "1.x-dev@dev" instead of e.g. "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8" . After that yes do a drush updb and a drush cr

Comment: My bad, I ran the command. and yes I do see "drupal/pathauto": "1.x-dev@dev" in the json file, but the error persists.