# How do I add a patch to patches in composer.json from the command line?

Tags: composer

In https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297530/69441

> Third, add an "extras" section in composer with a patch:

How do I do this without an interactive editor?

Answer (score 7):

```
composer config --merge --json extra.patches.drupal/tooltip_ckeditor '{"D10": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-08-16/tooltip_ckeditor.4.0.1.rector.patch"}'
```